# opening text file and change it in python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a big text file like this example:

example:

```
</Attributes>
FovCount,555
FovCounted,536
ScanID,1803C0555

BindingDensity,0.51
```

as you see some lines are empty, some are comma separated and some others have different format. 
I would like to open the file and look for the lines which start with these 3 words: `FovCount`, `FovCounted` and `BindingDensity`. if the line start with one of them I want to get the number after the `comma`. from the number related to `FovCount` and `FovCounted` I will make criteria and at the end the results is a list with 2 items: `criteria` and `BD` (which is the number after `BindingDensity`). I made the following function in python but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

```
def QC(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f.split(","):
            if line.startswith("FovCount"):
                FC = line[1]
            elif line.startswith("FovCounted"):
                FCed = line[1]
                criteria = FC/FCed
            elif line.startswith("BindingDensity"):
                BD = line[1]
    return [criteria, BD]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the file into lines separated by a comma (`,`). But lines aren't separated by a command, they are separated by a newline character (`\n`).

Try changing `f.split(",")` to `f.read().split("\n")` or you can use `f.readlines()` which basically does the same thing.

You can then split each line into comma-separated segments using `segments = line.split(",")`.

You can check if the first segment matches your text criteria: `if segments[0] == "FovCounted"`, etc.

You can then obtain the value by getting the second segment: `value = segments[1]`.